aws api gateway:CORS proxy
I make a simple API Gateway(REST api) to add file in s3 and it's look like this
(https://i.sstatic.net/pBtC6nlf.png)
And it's working on postman but when use with front-end it's have CORS proxy. I try to fix like a normal one, but it's still not work. I want to know that which path that i enabled CORS is different? I try enabled in "/" and "/{bucket}/{filename}" but still have the same error
i want to fix a normal cors proxy when use api-gateway

Please add more context. For example, the API configuration or documentation if there is any, the code you used to call it and the exact error you are receiving, the "normal fix", i.e., what you have tried already and explain how you called it successfully using Postman.
